# how to save the image with name posted in the request

Tags: php

I have this simple php file that read the image from my android application:

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];

$cod=$_REQUEST['cod_anagrafico'];

echo $base;

// base64 encoded utf-8 string

$binary=base64_decode($base);

//binary, utf-8 bytes

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

print($binary);

$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);

$file = fopen('docs/test2.jpg', 'wb');

fwrite($file, $binary);

fclose($file);

echo '<img src=docs/test.jpg>';

?>
```

But it save my pic with the standard name "test". So i need to save this image with the name of variable "cod". How can i do that? And how can i delete the image when the process end?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line and you should be ok

`$file = fopen("docs/{$cod}", 'wb');`

Comment: And if i want to delete the image? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming your script has permissions, unlink() should work just fine.  You'll need to know the full path.  Check your server settings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php